# Как преобразовать Lua скрипт из одной строки

Tags: lua

Мне нужно преобразовать lua скрипт в построчный, как это сделать?
Сам код:
по ссылке, он очень большой
https://text-host.ru/bez-zagolovka-6627

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь любым beautifier'ом, например вот [этим](https://goonlinetools.com/lua-beautifier/)